# Cannot change font color to black with CreateSpace package

Tags: color, color-profile

I am using a package called [CreateSpace](https://github.com/aginiewicz/createspace) but with the below code, the font color is more "brownish" than black. RGB(45,38,32) and not RGB(0,0,0) but I can't find anywhere in the files from that package where the font is set.

Can someone shed some light on this and how I can successfully get my black color back?

Side note: Is there maybe some reason as too why you might want non-black text color for books in print?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{createspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\color{black}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem here is that you are looking at a document with its own colourspace which is specifically designed to print correctly on the CreateSpace service. I suspect you will only see the colours correctly if your setup is properly calibrated and your viewer can handle colourspaces properly.

Comment: @ArTourter, Hm. OK! So you're saying that it will really be black when it is printed with their service? or at least, that is the idea?

Comment: To me that would be the idea. However I have never used their service and haven't got a calibrated set up to test. But you can do some weird things with colourspace. how do the pdf examples given you the github link you provided get displayed on your screen? I have also compiled your MWE and on my screen it look black on adobe reader under linux. could you link to the your sample pdf?

Comment: @ArTourter, I took a print screen and used the color picker in Photoshop to get the RGB values and it was not completely black. Here's a sample that I generated https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4396175/test.pdf

Comment: Your sample shows black here and the colour picker on my environment gets RGB(0,0,0). I definitely thing your environment doesn't handle the colourspace properly. As a matter of fact I have tried it on a Mac and get what you described when using Adobe Reader but using Preview I get RGB(0,0,0). This is definitely a colourspace interpretation issue. Your sceen has its own response, the system will try and match this by translating the colourspace of the document (usually RGB) to what the screen can handle. For printing it is the same: the printer will have its own response. [...]

Comment: @ArTourter, Thank you! You learn something new ever day.. :)

Comment: [...] When doing photography, one can spend a fair amount of time calibrating screen/printer/scanner... and photography software will be able to switch from one profile to another to show the user exactly how it will show and the different output devices. Most professional printing company will give you their own printer profile (has the ones provided by the CreateSpace package). Now how to get Adobe Reader to do the translation properly... I have no idea. I guess it will use the system profile and hand the translation to the OS requiring the user to calibrate the system properly.

Comment: @ArTourter, Ok, I think I understand. But since the PDF I generated looks black on your computer, that means if I use the correct profile, even if it does not look black on my screen, it will indeed be black in print. Thanks a lot. If you want, copy/paste your comments as an answer and I will accept that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are looking at a document with its own colourspace which is specifically designed to print correctly on the CreateSpace service. I suspect you will only see the colours correctly if your setup is properly calibrated and your viewer can handle colour profiles properly.

You can do some weird things with colourspace. how do the pdf examples given you the github link you provided get displayed on your screen? I have also compiled your MWE and on my screen it look black on adobe reader under linux.

Your sample shows black here and the colour picker on my environment gets RGB(0,0,0). I definitely thing your environment doesn't handle the colourspace properly. As a matter of fact I have tried it on a Mac and get what you described when using Adobe Reader but using Preview I get RGB(0,0,0). This is definitely a colourspace interpretation issue. Your sceen has its own response, the system will try and match this by translating the colourspace of the document (usually RGB) to what the screen can handle. For printing it is the same: the printer will have its own response.

When doing photography, one can spend a fair amount of time calibrating screen/printer/scanner... and photography software will be able to switch from one profile to another to show the user exactly how it will show and the different output devices. Most professional printing company will give you their own printer profile (as the ones provided by the CreateSpace package). Now how to get Adobe Reader to do the translation properly... I have no idea. I guess it will use the system profile and hand the translation to the OS requiring the user to calibrate the system properly.